# Deadlock detected when execute doctrine migration (aurora postgres)

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, amazon-aurora

## Context

### Environment

Back-end: symfony 4.4

Database: PostreSql 10.XX

#### Production server

- AWS EC2 instance, on Debian, who contain Back-end
- AWS Amazon-Aurora instance who contain Database

#### Testing server

EC2 instance, on Debian, who contain Back-end and Database

#### Development environment

Ubuntu, who contain Back-end and Database

### What i try to do

A very simple migration for add Gedmo\SotfDelete in many entities

```php
final class Version20211221101121 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return 'Add soft delete';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx DROP deleted_at');
    }
}
```

### Before I try to do it

- I have successfully tried to execute the migration on development environment
- I have successfully tried to execute the migration on the testing server

## Problem

When i try to execute the migration on production it throw an SQL error

***SQL error trace :***

```
  SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock detected: 7 ERROR:  deadlock detected                                                      
  DETAIL:  Process 19401 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 25783 of database 25651; blocked by process 20050.  
  Process 20050 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 25768 of database 25651; blocked by process 19401.               
  HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

***Doctrine error trace :***

```
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxx ADD deleted_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT  
   NULL':                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                             
  SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock detected: 7 ERROR:  deadlock detected                                                            
  DETAIL:  Process 19401 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 25783 of database 25651; blocked by process 20050.        
  Process 20050 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 25768 of database 25651; blocked by process 19401.                     
  HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

I have temporarily undo the commit while waiting to find the cause and the solution of this problem.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

### For explanation

Postgres preserve the integrity of relationships by assigning lock rules to tables during transactions. These rules are stored in the pg_lock table.

During the above-mentioned migration, one of the entities and in relation to all the others.

During the execution of the migration, this table is assigned an AccessExclusive type lock while the other tables are assigned an AccessShare type lock.

#### Nota bene

**AccessExclusiveLock**

- Prevents all other transactions from accessing the table in any way for the duration the lock is held
- Restrictive lock mode
- Acquired by most DDL statements (ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE)

**AccessShareLock**

- Only conflicts with AccessExclusiveLock
- Acquired by SELECT commands that are read-only

### How i solved the problem

I separated the table which was at the center of the relations in a second migration, by performing the migrations one after the other the conflict is avoided.